# Searching for a widget, which builds a list over the normal screen

Tags: flutter, layout, flutter-layout

Does sombody know how the widget is called, which showes a list, which is over the normal screen? The link bellow showes a screenshot from another app, which looks like I want it. I hope the screenshot makes it clear what I´m searching for. Thanks in advance!

[That´s the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6nOK6.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build using show dialog widget.

Following code help you to understand more.

Note: I demonstrated using new stateful widget, because in your screen shot you want to select radio button and changing state is not possible, so stateful widget is required. If you don't want to change ant state mean if you do not want to call setState then you can create widget where i call stateful widget.

```
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  MyAppState createState() => MyAppState();
}

class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  List list = List();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.red,
        child: Center(
          child: RaisedButton(
            child: Text("click!"),
            onPressed: () async {
              showDialog(
                  context: context,
                  builder: (_) {
                    return NewScreen();
                  });
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class NewScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _NewScreenState createState() => _NewScreenState();
}

class _NewScreenState extends State<NewScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
      color: Colors.transparent,
      elevation: 0.0,
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.white,
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(40),
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: 20,
          itemBuilder: (_, index) {
            return Text(index.toString());
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```